# Strange behaviour of abbreviations triggered with shift+enter in gvim+vim-latex

Tags: gvim, plugin-vim-latex, abbreviations

Playing with abbreviation in insert mode i noticed the following unexpected behaviour, *when using gvim with vim-latex plugin*:

Defining an abbreviation such as

```
:iab m <m>
```

or any similar "container" abbreviation such as

```
:iab m \(m\)
:iab m \m\
:iab m [m]
```

and so on, i get the expected behaviour when simply typing in insert mode

```
m<space>
```

However, if I type

```
m<shift><enter>
```

or

```
m<ctrl><enter>
```

the "container characters" are doubled, for example in the first two cases above I get

```
<<m>>
\(\(m\)\)
```

I don't find this kind of behaviour in the abbreviations section of the man page, nor in the relative vim.wikia page.

I'm using the vim version 7.4, and I can reproduce this both on Arch Linux and Windows 7.

Why does this happen? Can I prevent it? How?

### Developers mailing list

I submitted the problem on the [vim-latex mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vim-latex/).
[Here](http://sourceforge.net/p/vim-latex/mailman/vim-latex-devel/thread/542A8FBE.4000206@mathematik.tu-chemnitz.de/) is the response I got:

> Hi,
>
> this seems to be a strange interaction with the IMAP-features of the
>   latex-suite.
>
> I tried
>
> ```
> :iab a (m)
> :iab m [a]
> ```
>
> Now, `a<space>`  =>  `(m)` `a<s-space>` => `([a])`
>
> Here, first `a` is expanded to `(m)` and the inner `m` is expanded to `[a]`.
>
> If one uses
>
> ```
>  let Imap_FreezeImap=1
> ```
>
> `<space>` triggers no expansions, but `<s-space>` works correctly.
>
> I have no clue how to fix this.
>
> Best regards, Gerd

### Other unexpected behaviours

#### Using inoreab

Following a suggestion in the comments I tried with

```
:inoreab n <n>
```

When I do this something else happens: typing

```
n<space>
```

produces

```
* <n>
```

with a * character coming from nowhere.
Typing instead
`n<shift><space>`
or `n<enter>` or `n<ctrl><enter>`
I get the expected output `<n>`.
Can you reproduce this?

#### Without set backspace=eol,indent,start

Even without using recursive abbreviations, there is a problem if

```
set keyboard=eol,start,indent
```

is *not* used.

Defining an abbreviation like

```
:iab alice bob
```

and using it typing

```
alice<space>
```

**does not** substitute `alice` with `bob`. Instead places `bob` at the right of `alice`, producing an output like

```
alice bob
```

Again, using `<ctrl><space>` or `<enter>` the substitution is made correctly.

Comment: This is [cross-posted from stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26115471/4063051). The only reason I don't delete the post there is to have it more easily foundable via google search.

Comment: Have you tried using `:inoreab`?!

Comment: @IngoKarkat I just tried, and the result is very weird. See the edit

Answer (score 2):

Your updated findings give it away: The Latex plugin (incorrectly, that's why `:inoremap` causes the addition of a `*`) parses the output of the `:iab` command in `s:LookupCharacter(char)` from `plugin/imaps.vim`:

```
            " An extremeley wierd way to get around the fact that vim
            " doesn't have the equivalent of the :mapcheck() function for
            " abbreviations.
            let _a = @a
            exec "redir @a | silent! iab ".lastword." | redir END"
```

So, the problem is with the plugin's `IMAP()` function, which purportedly has the following

```
" Motivation:
" this script provides a way to generate insert mode mappings which do not
" suffer from some of the problem of mappings and abbreviations while allowing
" cursor placement after the expansion. It can alternatively be thought of as
" a template expander.
```

Therefore, it's a bug in the plugin; you either need to wait for / submit a patch, or avoid the problem by not defining such `:iab` yourself. (Maybe using the provided `IMAP()` function consistently will solve this?)

Comment: thanks for the very useful answer. I [submitted](http://sourceforge.net/p/vim-latex/mailman/vim-latex-devel/?viewmonth=201502) this problem on the [developers](http://sourceforge.net/p/vim-latex/mailman/vim-latex-devel/) mailing list. Let's see if they confirm and possibly fix the issue.